# set open in jquery accordion menu

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui-accordion

I have a working jquery accordion menu that I have follow from this link. 
http://perishablepress.com/jquery-accordion-menu-tutorial/#

But then I open a menu and I click on a link, the menu closes again. I want that the menu stays open, and only closes when a another menu will open.

Sorry for my english, here is the jquery code

```
var checkElement = $(this).next();

$('#cssmenu li').removeClass('active');
$(this).closest('li').addClass('active');   


if((checkElement.is('ul')) && (checkElement.is(':visible'))) {
  $(this).closest('li').removeClass('active');
  checkElement.slideUp('normal');
}

if((checkElement.is('ul')) && (!checkElement.is(':visible'))) {
  $('#cssmenu ul ul:visible').slideUp('normal');
  checkElement.slideDown('normal');
}

if (checkElement.is('ul')) {
  return false;
} else {
  return true;  
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about try this:

```js
<!-- JS -->
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function($) {
    $('#accordion').find('.accordion-toggle').click(function(){

      //Expand or collapse this panel
      $(this).next().slideToggle('fast');

      //Hide the other panels
      $(".accordion-content").not($(this).next()).slideUp('fast');

    });
  });
</script>
```

```css
<!-- CSS -->
  .accordion-toggle {cursor: pointer;}
  .accordion-content {display: none;}
  .accordion-content.default {display: block;}
```

```html
<!-- HTML -->
<div id="accordion">
  <h4 class="accordion-toggle">Accordion 1</h4>
  <div class="accordion-content default">
    <p>Cras malesuada ultrices augue molestie risus.</p>
  </div>
  <h4 class="accordion-toggle">Accordion 2</h4>
  <div class="accordion-content">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet mauris eu turpis.</p>
  </div>
  <h4 class="accordion-toggle">Accordion 3</h4>
  <div class="accordion-content">
    <p>Vivamus facilisisnibh scelerisque laoreet.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually the problem is that the container li listener is being executed when you are clicking on the child li elements, so is always doing a toggle of the actual state.

Following your approach the easiest way of solve it is addding some css classes, so you can recognize if the clicked element isthe root li or a child li.

For example you can add a class to the child links like 'sub-link' to recognize them and then on the listener you just check if the target element is not a sub link to do add and remove the active class:

```js
$('#cssmenu li').on('click', function(e){
    var $target = $(e.target),
        $currentElement = $(this);
        
    if (!$target.hasClass('sub-link') && !$currentElement.hasClass('active')){
        var $activeElement = $('#cssmenu li.active');
        $activeElement.find('ul').slideUp('normal');
        $activeElement.removeClass('active');
        
        $currentElement.addClass('active');
        $currentElement.find('ul').slideDown('normal');
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="cssmenu">
 <ul>
  <li><a href="#"><span>Home</span></a></li>
  <li><a href="#"><span>Products</span></a>
   <ul class='sub-link-list' style='display: none;'>
    <li><a class='sub-link' href="#">Widgets</a></li>
    <li><a class='sub-link' href="#">Menus</a></li>
    <li><a class='sub-link' href="#">Products</a></li>
   </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#"><span>Company</span></a>
   <ul class='sub-link-list' style='display: none;'>
    <li><a class='sub-link' href="#">About</a></li>
    <li><a class='sub-link' href="#">Location</a></li>
   </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#"><span>Contact</span></a></li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5ovn7Laj/

I hope it helps!